# Convert text data into multidimensional array in C#:

Tags: c#

I have a following string, with line breaks in a textfile:

```
Card No.      Seq     Account 1   Account 2  Account 3  Account 4   Customer Name          Expiry   Status

0100000184998  1   2500855884500                 -          -       /NIRMAL PRADHAN          1302     Cold
0100000186936  1                      -          -          -       /RITA SHRESTHA           1302     Cold
0100000238562  1   2500211214500                 -          -       /HARRY SHARMA            1301     Cold
0100000270755  0   1820823730100      -          -                  /EXPRESS ACCOUNT         9999     Cold
0100000272629  0   1820833290100      -          -          -       /ROMA MAHARJAN           1208     Cold
0100000272637  0   2510171014500      -                     -       /NITIN KUMAR SHRESTHA    1208     Cold
0100000272645  0   1800505550100      -          -          -       /DR HARI BHATTA          1208     Cold
```

Here,

- `Card No`., `Seq` has fixed digits.
- `Account 1, Account 2, Account 3, Account 4` can have `fixed digit
  number` or `-` or  `null`.
- Customer Name can have `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Middle Name` etc.

My desired result is:

```
array[0][0] = "0100000184998"
array[0][1] = "1"
array[0][2] = "2500855884500"
array[0][3] = " "
array[0][4] = "-"
array[0][6] = "NIRMAL PRADHAN "

array[1][0] = "0100000186936"
array[1][1] = "1"
array[1][3] = " "
array[1][4] = "-"
```

Here, What I tried is:

```
 var sourceFile = txtProcessingFile.Text;
string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sourceFile);
    var newarr =  contents.Split(new char[]{ '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select (x => 
      x.Split(new char[]{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray()
    ).ToArray();


DataTable dt = new DataTable("NewDataTable");   


dt.Columns.Add("CardNo");
dt.Columns.Add("SNo");
dt.Columns.Add("Account1");
and so on...

for (int row = 0; row < newarr.Length; row++)
{

   for (int col = 0; col < newarr[col].Length; col++)
   {
      dt.Rows.Add(newarr[row]);
      row++;

   }


}
```

This works fine if data field is not empty and Customer name is only the first name or delimited.

But, here what I am trying to get is:

- `First Name`, `Middle Name` or `Last Name` must be stored in the same
  array element.
- `Account Number` in the array element must left blank if it is blank.

  How is it possible to store it correctly on the datatable ?

Comment: `Expiry` and `Status` will always have non-empty values?

Comment: yes..(but, my assumption is if it can be implemented in account number, it wouldn't be problem in Expiry and Status.)

Comment: **1.** Since you are using only space to seperate data-entities in the file, use a spacial character to store First-name and last name. eg. Harry<?/>SHARMA. You can remove <?/> while reading. **2.** Same way use a special symbol to designate blank character, say use <?#?> if account no. is blank, and remove it while file reading operation.

Comment: @GrantWinney I have no control on text data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you learn to use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class. Yes, it's in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace, but you can use it from C#. That class lets you easily parse text files that have fixed field widths. See the article [How to: Read From Fixed-width Text Files in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx) for an example. Again, the sample is in Visual Basic, but it should be very easy to convert to C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to make the compromise of not making a difference between `-` and `null` values in the account values, you may try this:

```
var sourceFile = txtProcessingFile.Text;
string[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile);
DataTable dt = new DataTable("NewDataTable");

dt.Columns.Add("CardNo");
dt.Columns.Add("SNo");
dt.Columns.Add("Account1");
dt.Columns.Add("Account2");
dt.Columns.Add("Account3");
dt.Columns.Add("Account4");
dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName");
dt.Columns.Add("Expiry");
dt.Columns.Add("Status");

for (int row = 2; row < contents.Length; row++)
{
    var newRow = dt.NewRow();
    var regEx = new Regex(@"([\w]*)");
    var matches = regEx.Matches(contents[row].ToString())
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Where(m => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Value))
        .ToList();
    var numbers = matches.Where(m => Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, @"^\d+$")).ToList();
    var names = matches.Where(m => !Regex.IsMatch(m.Value, @"^\d+$")).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        newRow[i] = numbers.Skip(i).First();
    }
    newRow[newRow.ItemArray.Length - 2] = numbers.Last();
    newRow[newRow.ItemArray.Length - 1] = names.Last();
    newRow[newRow.ItemArray.Length - 3] = names.Take(names.Count() - 1).Aggregate<Match, string>("", (a, b) => a += " " + b.Value);
    dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around the names with a single space in them, you could try splitting on a double-space instead of a single space:

```
x.Split(new string[]{ "  " }
```

This still won't fix the issue with columns that have no value in them. It appears that your text file has everything in a specific position. `Seq` is in position 16, `Account 1` is in position 20, etc.

Once your lines are stored in `newarr`, you may just want to use `String.Substring()` with `.Trim()` to get the value in each column.